# Error SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:4200' did not find 'http://localhost:4200' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response

Tags: angular2-http

Actually I am trying to connect an Angular app with my Maven-Jersey-webapp(implements Rest Services concept) and getting this error.

More Details:
I am using Oracle10g XE Database
Eclipse IDE for maven Project(http://localhost:8080/MavenProject)
Angular CLI(http://localhost:4200/)

I want to retrieve data from database(Stored in students table) and then display that data in Angular App in a Table
my jersey project returns the table data in JSON and XML format(Running Successfully)

[retrieving student table data in JSON format using Maven-jersey-webapp implementing rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuouS.png)

[angular code making get request using HttpClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enemu.png)

[error which i get while making get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEO9C.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by checking if you are using

```
http vs https
```

Just use **http** to fix it. After that, Add that in the header in the angular service you created like doing a code like this

```
 const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200', // -->Add this line
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            })
        };
```

Just check the string value you passed in your code.
Sometimes your eye gets trick on these values. Like

**http**://localhost:4200 vs **https**://localhost:4200

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error.

The issue was in the .net core web api project. The method I made a post to, had a object defined in the parameter list, without an empty constructor.

The CORS error was really misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. 
Add config.EnableCors(); in WebApiConfig.Register method.