# Reactjs can't read smart contract?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, access-control, web3js, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have a project in ReactJs where I use web3.js to read from the smart contract and I an Ethereum client provided by Infura. Problem is, when I access my project in Google Chrome, everything works fine. 
If I access my project via Microsoft Edge, I am getting the following error:

> SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:3000' did not find
>   'http://localhost:3000' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response
>   header for cross-origin  resource at
>   'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/censored'.

I looked into other posts and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714097/error-sec7120-cors-the-origin-http-localhost4200-did-not-find-http-lo) which didn't solve my problem.

Other things I have noticed:
If I access the website from Internet Explorer, I can read data as normal. If I go to Google Chrome and not use MetaMask, I can read data as normal. If I activate MetaMask and I don't select the correct infura network (Ropsten) and I choose for example Main Network, it doesn't work as expected

UPDATE:
Seems that it's not an issue from my side and instead it comes from Infura. I enquired them to see if Microsoft Edge is a limitation of their service and if they are willing to do anything with it.

Comment: It's a CORS error. It has nothing to do with reactjs, it just means the base url you are querying from is different from the one you are querying too, which your target does not allow. Hard to say what without seeing any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah the good old CORS problem. Since you don't have control of the server's CORS settings, you're better off creating a small server side application that will proxy these requests on behalf of your react application.

Comment: I want to understand something. So technically this CORS problem occurs only when testing applications locally? Because I wouldn't mind deploying it to clients since I can still test it in Google Chrome so it doesn't affect my experience

Comment: @Cristian CORS is a security measure, you'll experience this same issue in production. It's a setting on the smart contract's "server". It's kind of a pain, but if you're curious about why and how it works - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS